# How to disable jboss 7.1.1 AS standalone.log file in log folder on windows

Tags: jboss

Our JBoss 7.1.1 AS app server creates to files in the standalone log folder with incomplete startup messages in server.log and standalone.log.

The standalone.log grows so large and degrades the performance of the application.

How should we disable this standalone.log in the /standalone/log folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Jboss handles appends logs in multiple files (standalone.logs,server.logs) you can deactivate the log handler  using the CLI :

```
/subsystem=logging/logging=root-logger:remove-handler(name=CONSOLE)
```

The Jboss community allways recommand to configure the logging subsystem to match your needs in the app ( logging levels, properties, replication...) and configure the logging.properties file with the specific app properties.

[here is an example of the logging.properties file](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.3/html/development_guide/example_logging.properties_file)

[Jboss logging Doc](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.3/html/development_guide/sect-logging_with_the_jboss_logging_framework#About_JBoss_Logging)

Comment: Thanks to you Hajed. This has been resolved as advised. All logged messages have stopped been written to the standalone.log file.

Comment: Welcome, Good to hear that  ;)